# Extract Last Word in String with Swift

Tags: ios, string, swift

What is the way of extracting last word in a String in Swift? So if I have "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet", return "amet". What is the most efficient way of doing this?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can use String method enumerateSubstringsInRange. First parameter just pass your string `Range<Index>`, and the option `.byWords`. Just append each substring to the resulting collection and return it.

**Swift 5 or later** (for older Swift syntax check edit history)

```
import Foundation

extension StringProtocol { // for Swift 4 you need to add the constrain `where Index == String.Index` 
    var byWords: [SubSequence] {
        var byWords: [SubSequence] = []
        enumerateSubstrings(in: startIndex..., options: .byWords) { _, range, _, _ in
            byWords.append(self[range])
        }
        return byWords
    }
}
```

---

Usage:

```
let sentence = "Out of this world!!!"
let words = sentence.byWords             // ["Out", "of", "this", "world"]
let firstWord = words.first      // "Out"
let lastWord = words.last         // world"
let first2Words = words.prefix(2) // ["Out", "of"]
let last2Words = words.suffix(2)   // ["this", "world"]
```

---

**Without import Foundation**

Cleaning punctuation characters filtering the letters and spaces of the string

```
let clean = sentence.filter{ $0.isLetter || $0.isWhitespace }
```

find the index after the index of the last space in a string

```
if let lastIndex = clean.lastIndex(of: " "), let index = clean.index(lastIndex, offsetBy: 1, limitedBy: clean.index(before: clean.endIndex)) {
    let lastWord = clean[index...]
    print(lastWord)   // "world"
}
```

find the index of the first space in a string

```
if let index = clean.firstIndex(of: " ") {
    let firstWord = clean[...index]
    print(firstWord)  // "Out""
}
```

Comment: Nice, although I'd be hesitant to have an extension that promotes a computed property with at least `O(n)` performance. I'd be more inclined to make it a function, since that makes it clear that it's doing work every time you call it.

Comment: @DuncanC Thanks but I did already here https://stackoverflow.com/a/39667966/2303865 You can remove the computed properties and use the method only `components(separated: .byWords)`

Comment: @UtkuDalmaz There is no word that starts with `"#"`. Btw it does return the last word `"world"` without the hashtag

Answer (score 16):

The other answers are fine if you want to include Foundation classes. If you want to use Swift-only classes then you can do it this way:

One way to do it is to use indices. This is probably the fastest way with long strings:

Swift 4:

```
let str = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"
let size = str.reversed().firstIndex(of: " ") ?? str.count
let startWord = str.index(str.endIndex, offsetBy: -size)
let last = str[startWord...] // -> "amet"
```

Or you could split the string:

Swift 4:

```
let str = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"
let split = str.split(separator: " ")
let last    = String(split.suffix(1).joined(separator: [" "]))
let lastTwo = String(split.suffix(2).joined(separator: [" "]))

print(last)    // -> "amet"
print(lastTwo) // -> "sit amet”
```

Swift 3:

```
let str = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"
let split = str.characters.split(separator: " ")
let last    = String(split.suffix(1).joined(separator: [" "]))
let lastTwo = String(split.suffix(2).joined(separator: [" "]))

print(last)    // -> "amet"
print(lastTwo) // -> "sit amet”
```

Swift 2:

```
let str = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"
let split = str.characters.split(Character(" "))
let last    = String(split.suffix(1).joinWithSeparator([" "]))
let lastTwo = String(split.suffix(2).joinWithSeparator([" "]))

print(last)    // -> "amet"
print(lastTwo) // -> "sit amet"
```

Comment: nice solution but a word can be separated by a comma or punctuation mark too

Comment: The example in the question used spaces but the techniques work for any character. You could also use the method`firstIndex(where:)` like this: `str.reversed().firstIndex { Set(" ,!.?;").contains($0) }` and it could be combined with `CharacterSet.punctuationCharacters` too.

Answer (score 10):

I would also consider using [`componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:), and using the whitespace character set:

```
let string = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"
let stringArray = string.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet())
print(stringArray.last)
```

Comment: I like your approach! Thanks a lot! Is it possible to get the last two words with this approach or should I use a for loop?

Comment: Don't forget to add `import Foundation` to the answer. The example won't work without it.

Comment: Are you sure? You might have imported it somewhere. [`String`](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_String_Structure/index.html) doesn't have the method `componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet`. That method is part of `NSString`.

Answer (score 9):

First use `componentsSeparatedByString` to split your string into an array by space, then get the last word of the array using `.last`

```
var string = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"
var stringArr = string.componentsSeparatedByString(" ")

var lastWord = stringArr.last //amet
```

Comment: For Swift 4, swift 5 and upper: .components(separatedBy: " ")

Answer (score 3):

Swift 5

```
extension String {

    func trim(_ emptyToNil: Bool = true)->String? {
        let text = self.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines)
        return emptyToNil && text.isEmpty ? nil : text
    }

    var lastWord: String? {
        if let size = self.lastIndex(of: " "), size >= self.startIndex {
            return String(self[size...]).trim()
        }
        return nil
    }

}
```

Usage

```
print("Out of this world!!!".lastWord ?? "") // world!!!
```

Answer (score 1):

The same solution by '@Leo Dabus' but without slices: (Swift 4.x)

```
    let fullName = "Williams Diaz Robert"
    let words = fullName.components(separatedBy: " ")
    if(words.count < 2) {
        return
    }
    let fistName = String(words.last ?? "") //Robert
    let lastNameArray = words.prefix(words.count - 1)   //["Williams","Diaz"]: [String]
    let lastName = lastNameArray.joined(separator: " ") // "Williams Diaz"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let  value = "Hello, I am a String"
let stringArray = value.components(separatedBy: .whitespaces)
let lastWord = stringArray.last ?? ""
print(lastWord)
```