# How to return a first word from a string in Swift?

Tags: swift, string, swift-playground

If we have, for example, situation like this:

```
 var myString = "Today was a good day"
```

What is the best way to return the first word, which is "Today"? I think mapping should be applied, but not sure how.

Thanks.

Answer (score 23):

The simplest way I can think of is

#### Swift 3

```
let string = "hello world"
let firstWord = string.components(separatedBy: " ").first
```

#### Swift 2.2

```
let string = "hello world"
let firstWord = string.componentsSeparatedByString(" ").first
```

and if you think you need to use it a lot in your code, make it as an `extension`

```
extension String {
    func firstWord() -> String? {
        return self.components(separatedBy: " ").first
    }
}
```

#### Usage

```
let string = "hello world"
let firstWord = string.firstWord()
```

Comment: Depending on the string, this might be too naive. E.g., "Hello, World!" would yield "Hello," which may or may not be what you wanted. Maybe try

```let separators = " ,.;:*?" /* word boundaries */

let components = self.components(separatedBy: CharacterSet.init(charactersIn: separators) )

let firstWord = components.first```?

Answer (score 11):

You can use StringProtocol method `enumerateSubstrings(in: Range<String.Index>)` with options `.byWords` to enumerate the words in your string and just get the first element:

**Swift 5.1 • Xcode 11 or later**

Note: For older Swift syntax check this post edit [history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/39667966/revisions)

```
import Foundation

extension StringProtocol {

    var byLines: [SubSequence] { components(separated: .byLines) }
    var byWords: [SubSequence] { components(separated: .byWords) }

    func components(separated options: String.EnumerationOptions)-> [SubSequence] {
        var components: [SubSequence] = []
        enumerateSubstrings(in: startIndex..., options: options) { _, range, _, _ in components.append(self[range]) }
        return components
    }

    var firstWord: SubSequence? {
        var word: SubSequence?
        enumerateSubstrings(in: startIndex..., options: .byWords) { _, range, _, stop in
            word = self[range]
            stop = true
        }
        return word
    }
    var firstLine: SubSequence? {
        var line: SubSequence?
        enumerateSubstrings(in: startIndex..., options: .byLines) { _, range, _, stop in
            line = self[range]
            stop = true
        }
        return line
    }
}
```

---

Playground Testing:

```
let string = "• Today was a good day.\n• Tomorrow will be better.\n"

let firstWord = string.firstWord                               // "Today"
let firstLine = string.firstLine                               // "• Today was a good day."
let firstLineLastWord = string.firstLine?.byWords.last         // day
let firstLineLast2Words = string.firstLine?.byWords.suffix(2)  // ["good", "day"]
```

Answer (score 6):

I would prefer using `CharacterSet`, since words can be delimited by white-spaces as well as punctuation marks.

```
var myString    = "Today was a good day"
let nonLetters  = CharacterSet.letters.inverted
let first       = myString.components(separatedBy: nonLetters).first
```

Comment: Perfect! Beautiful and elegant solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid processing the whole string just to get the first word, you could do this:

```
let string = "Hello World"
let word1  = string.prefix{ (c:Character) in CharacterSet.letters.contains(c.unicodeScalars.first!) }
```

Comment: Note that If you don't want to enumerate the whole string you can stop the enumeratedSubsrtrings in range after finding the first word.

Comment: Why not simply `prefix {  $0 != " " }`?  If you are extra paranoid `prefix {  String($0).rangeOfCharacter(from: .whitespaces) == nil }` or using the letters approach `prefix {  String($0).rangeOfCharacter(from: .letters) != nil }` Note that all of this only work if the word is at the beginning of the string. try `"•Sugar"`

Comment: I wanted to make sure that any non-letter delimiter would be detected (not just spaces). Also, transforming each letter into a string for processing didn't seem as straightforward (or efficient) to me.

Comment: Using only the first Unicode value doesn't seem also correct

Comment: It would not work for composite unicode characters such as emojis but for all roman character sets it does work.

Comment: What about Chinese letters?

Comment: They should work as well (they all have their own block in unicode) although I have not thoroughly researched the subject.  "你好，世界" --> "你好"

Comment: I still think using the enumerator with a stop at the first  occurrence a better option when importing Foundation. It also covers non letters before the first word. What if your string starts with an empty space?

Comment: Agreed if the requirement considers that an empty word is to be ignored (which is likely but not explicitly stated)

Answer (score 0):

Try using `prefix()` function

```
let string = "Today was a good day"
if let spaceIndex = string.firstIndex(of: " ") {
    let firstWord = String(string.prefix(upTo: string.index(after: spaceIndex)))
    print(firstWord)      // Today
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Elegant solution:

```
extension String {

    var firstWord: String {
        self.components(separatedBy: " ").first ?? ""
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
let myString = "Today was a good day"
print(myString.firstWord)
```

output:

```
Today
```