# Cannot use mutating member on immutable value inside a closure

Tags: swift, swift3

I try to capitalize the first letter of each word of a string, and I have the following code:

```
func makeHeadline(string: String) -> String {
        let headline = words.map { (word) -> String in
        var word = word
        let firstCharacter = word.remove(at: word.startIndex)
        return "\(String(firstCharacter).uppercased())\(word)"
        }.joined(separator: " ")

        return headline
    }
```

However, I get the following error:

> Cannot use mutating member on immutable value: 'word' is a 'let' constant.

I tried adding var before word `(var word)`, but I get the error:

> Parameters may not have the 'var' specifier.

How can I solve this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/29261218/2303865

Comment: @LeoDabus, thank you, but I wanted to implement this function by myself because of a TDD course I am following. Definitely your solution avoids reinventing the wheel.

Comment: I would suggest using https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsstring/1416774-enumeratesubstrings byWords options

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39667966/2303865

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make a local mutable copy:

```
func makeHeadline(string: String) -> String {
    let words = string.components(separatedBy: " ")

    let headline = words.map { (word) -> String in
        var word = word
        let firstCharacter = word.removeAtIndex(word.startIndex)
        return String(firstCharacter).uppercaseString + word
    }.joined(separator: " ")

    return headline
}
```

Comment: your code works, but what is the difference between var word insider the closure and (word)? It is like confusing for me. Btw, thank you so much for your response.

Comment: I don't understand your question, if that was a question

Comment: when you say `var word = word` how the compiler differentiates the closure argument, and the local mutable copy?

Comment: The mutable copy shadows the immutable parameter