# Swift: How to split a string and then extract specific substring?

Tags: ios, swift, string, nsstring

Example String -

> exampleString ( 123 )

I want two parts from the above string -

1-) `exampleString` by splitting

2-) `123` by splitting and then removing brackets and two spaces, one at each end

> More specifically, I want to know how can I extract a string between
>   two brackets ( )

How to achieve that in swift 4.2?

Thanks

Comment: Is there gonna be space between the number and brackets as you wrote, I mean is it gonna be like this `(123)` or `( 123 )`

Comment: With space - ( 123 )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a solution below, it will extract any string between brackets into an array without brackets, it also gives you string without element as word as an array element:

```
var myString = "exampleString ( 123 ) "

//creates result array from String by separating elements by space
var result = myString.split(separator: " ")

//filters array to remove '(' and ')'
result = result.filter { $0 != "(" && $0 != ")" }

print(result)
```

Then if you want to build a String back from result array with string elements, do the following:

```
var resultString = result.joined(separator: " ")

print(resultString)
```

Might not be ideal, but it might be useful for you.

Comment: Worked for me, I answered my own question but serving just one purpose. But your's served both purposes. Thanks!

Comment: This is not what OP asked

Comment: @MasterAgentX if you need to get all words from a string you can use string method enumerateSubstrings(in Range) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37535441/extract-last-word-in-string-with-swift/37536996#37536996

Answer (score 1):

I found this beautiful String Extension for slicing a string. It is answered here -

[Slice String Extension](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31727051/6348709)

```
extension String {
    func slice(from: String, to: String) -> String? {
        return (range(of: from)?.upperBound).flatMap { substringFrom in
        (range(of: to, range: substringFrom..<endIndex)?.lowerBound).map { substringTo in
            String(self[substringFrom..<substringTo])
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here I can simply get a substring like

```
let str = "exampleString ( 123 )"
print(str.slice(from: "( ", to: " )"))
```