# Getting Error with NSStringEnumerationOptions.ByWords - Swift 4.2

Tags: swift, nsstring, nsrange

I am trying to add this `Extension` to my code in order to  enumerate substrings by words. The source of this code was dated 2015, so this is apparently an earlier version of `Swift`. I'm using `Swift4.2` and I can't figure out how to properly update the code in the line identified below with a note.

```
extension String {
    func words() -> [String] {

        let range = Range<String.Index>(start: self.startIndex, end: self.endIndex) // THIS LINE CAUSES ERROR
        var words = [String]()

        self.enumerateSubstringsInRange(range, options: NSStringEnumerationOptions.ByWords) { (substring, _, _, _) -> () in
            words.append(substring)
        }

        return words
    }
}
```

I initially get this Error: ***Incorrect argument labels in call (have 'start:end:', expected '_:in:')***

I follow the "Fix" prompt and it changes the line to this:

`let range = Range<String.Index>(self.startIndex, in: self.endIndex)`

Then, I get this Error with no Fix suggestion:

***Cannot convert value of type 'String.Index' to expected argument type 'NSRange' (aka '_NSRange')***

The Errors are probably due to a `Swift` version update and I can't figure out the proper way to write this line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The enumerate substrings in range method syntax has changed a bit since Swift3:

The new declaration:

> func enumerateSubstrings(in range: R, options opts:
>   String.EnumerationOptions = default, _ body: @escaping (String?,
>   Range, Range, inout Bool) -> Void) where R
>   : RangeExpression, R.Bound == String.Index

```
extension String {
    func words() -> [String] {
        var words = [String]()
        enumerateSubstrings(in: startIndex..., options: .byWords) { substring, _, _, _ in
            words.append(substring!)
        }
        return words
    }
}
```

---

```
"abc def".words()  //  ["abc", "def"]
```

Note that in Swift 4 or later you should extend `StringProtocol` instead of the type `String` itself to support `Substring`s as well. You can check how to implement it at the answer I posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37536996/2303865)

Comment: Do you know if there is a `Swift` built-in function to identify whether or not a `String` contains an English word?

Comment: No there isn't. But you can check if the word is English or not

Comment: Can you point me to a `Swift` algorithm that can identify if a `String` is an English word?

Comment: `extension String {
    var isEnglishWord: Bool {
        return UITextChecker().rangeOfMisspelledWord(in: self, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: utf16.count), startingAt: 0, wrap: false, language: "en_US").location == NSNotFound
    }
}`

Comment: Since you obviously know your code. I have to ask one more question ... What if I have a `Set` of `Strings` and I want to loop through the `Set` in order to identify the `Strings` that are English words? The reason why I am trying to do this is b/c I am trying to solve a "Phone Words" algorithm question. The question requires an algorithm that will identify all of the possible English words that a given phone number can be mapped to. I have it mostly complete. Now, I just need to be able to loop through a `Set` of mapped out `Strings` and properly identify any English words.