# Text file to array in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to create a dictionary app on IOS. I have a text file (words_alpha.txt) in my Bundle, and I want to read all the words/lines, and place them into an arrray. String = ["word1",  "word2", "word3"]. Here is my current code I got from bit.ly/39IC642

```
let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "words_alpha", ofType: "txt") // file path for file "words_alpha.txt"
let string = try String(contentsOfFile: path!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
```

I am getting this error: Cannot use instance member 'path' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available

I am fairly new to using Swift and coding in general, please be detailed with your answers. Thank you!

Comment: The issue there is that you can't access  path value at instantiation time. It hasn't been initialized yet. You can solve your issue putting it on a single line `let string = try! String(contentsOfFile: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "words_alpha", ofType: "txt")!, encoding: .utf8)` or move your string instantiation to your view controller viewDidLoad method.

Comment: Another option is to declare your string as lazy var. `lazy var string = try! String(contentsOfFile: path!, encoding: .utf8)`

Comment: thanks I did your method, fix that problem. However when I am trying to add string[indexPath.row] to one of my cells of tableView, it gives me error "Cannot assign value of type 'Character' to type 'String'". Is my Variable 'string' not a list of words of Array? How do i turn 'string' from character to an array of string?

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you edit your question and post the contents of your text file. If you need to convert the string loaded from your text file to a list of words you can check this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/37536996/2303865

Answer (score 0):

If you are writing an iOS app, you can move such initialization into `viewDidLoad()`:

```
    var wordArray: [String] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //...
        let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "words_alpha", withExtension: "txt")! // file URL for file "words_alpha.txt"
        do {
            let string = try String(contentsOf: url, encoding: .utf8)
            wordArray = string.components(separatedBy: CharacterSet.newlines)
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
```

If your `words_alpha.txt` does contain multiple words per line, you may need some other way.