# Get last sentence from String after ". "(Dot And Space)

Tags: ios, swift, regex, string

I am trying to get the last sentence from String after ". "(Dot And Space), Suppose I have a very long string and in that string, there are multiple ". "(Dot And Space) but I want to fetch the String after the very last ". "(Dot And Space) I have tried some of the solutions but I am getting below error

**Example String: "Hello. playground!. Hello. World!!! How Are you All?"**

**Expected Output Needed: "World!!! How Are you All?"**

Below is the code which I have tried so far

```
let fullstring = "Hello. playground!. Hello. World!!! How Are you All?"
let outputString = fullstring.substringAfterLastOccurenceOf(". ") // Here I am getting this error Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'Character'


extension String {
    
    var nsRange: NSRange {
        return Foundation.NSRange(startIndex ..< endIndex, in: self)
    }
    
    subscript(nsRange: NSRange) -> Substring? {
        return Range(nsRange, in: self)
            .flatMap { self[$0] }
    }
    
    func substringAfterLastOccurenceOf(_ char: Character) -> String {
        
        let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "\(char)\\s*(\\S[^\(char)]*)$")
        if let match = regex.firstMatch(in: self, range: self.nsRange), let result = self[match.range(at: 1)] {
            return String(result)
        }
        return ""
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me with this or is there any other way to achieve this?

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: Similar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37535441/extract-last-word-in-string-with-swift

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `components(separatedBy:)` instead

```swift
let fullstring = "Hello. playground!. Hello. World!!! How Are you All?"
let sliptArr = fullstring.components(separatedBy: ". ")
print(sliptArr[sliptArr.count - 1]) // World!!! How Are you All?
```

Comment: For your second example, `spit` separator takes `self.Element` which is a Character and not a string.

Comment: Dear @JohnHanley, I was mistaken. Thank you sir

Answer (score 0):

if you are using `swift 5.7+` and `iOS 16.0+` u can use ```[regexBuilder](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/regexbuilder)'''.

```
let text = "Hello. playground!. Hello. World!!! How Are you All?"

let regex = Regex {
    Optionally{
        ZeroOrMore(.any)
        ". "
    }

    Capture {
        ZeroOrMore(.any)
    }
}

if let lastSentence = try? regex.wholeMatch(in: text) {
    print("lastSentence: \(lastSentence.output.1)")
}
```